# Unity: Correctly Modifing a RenderTexture in VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have basic working VR Application. At a given point. I would like to show a static image that covers the screen. I had the idea to load it into a material and the modify the render texture. Like so:

```
void OnRenderObject() {
    Graphics.Blit(RenderTexture.active, RenderTexture.active, mat);
}
```

However this doesn't really work. The player shows black as does the left eye. But the right eye shows the image.

How (and where) should I apply the mat to the render texture so that it looks good on VR AND appears correctly in the player as well?

Comment: in general showing a static image in VR is not really recommendable due to cyber sickness. Have you tried using [`OnPostRender`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html) or [`OnRenderImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html) instead?

Comment: @derHugo. I have tried both. Same result. Furthermore, cyber sickness is not a problem for that. this is not a game. We are constantly going to be showing static images, like an slide show.

Comment: Are you using the Oculus SDK?

Comment: @LorenzoGoldoni XR. This is currently working on HP Reverb

Comment: If your FOW is fixed (usually the XR SDK likes to overwrite it, so probably it is), you can place a plane under your head in the hierarchy with the material on it, and show it, when you want.

Comment: @h4ri I'm not sure I understand. Could you provide some code sample?

Comment: @aarelovich From the code, you only need to set the plane's GameObject active state with `SetActive()` to `true` if you want to show it or `false` if you want to hide it. You can place the plane in the editor and adjust its sizes to fit the screen and place it in the hierarchy under the head's transform to follow its rotation. But as derHugo said, the stationary image can cause motion sickness.